# How to recover corrupt sstates in PCSX2?

Tags: final-fantasy-12, pcsx2

Okay, I have a few FFXII IZJS save states:

- SS00.p2s
- SS01.p2s
- SS02.p2s

All the SS are corrupt. They have this corrupt message:
`> Selected savestate slot 1
Loading savestate from slot 1...
    filename: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\PCSX2\sstates\SLPM-66750 (1E7A88A7).01.p2s
EE/iR5900-32 Recompiler Reset
    Loading GS
Unexpected end of file or stream.
Path: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\PCSX2\sstates\SLPM-66750 (1E7A88A7).01.p2s
(pxActionEvent) (VM_UnzipFromDisk)`

But, somehow I able to recover SS01 and  SS02 SS. I recover the SS by loading a new created SS after loading the corrupt SS. There is a message displayed in the PCSX:

`> Selected savestate slot 8
Loading savestate from slot 8...
    filename: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\PCSX2\sstates\SLPM-66750 (1E7A88A7).08.p2s
[wx] invalid zip file
Savestate is corrupt or incomplete!
Path: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\PCSX2\sstates\SLPM-66750 (1E7A88A7).08.p2s
(pxActionEvent) Savestate file does not contain 'PCSX2 Savestate Version.id'(VM_UnzipFromDisk)`

Using this method, the SS01 is loaded and works. But, I unable to recover SS00. Using the same method, I only able to recover the BGM and sound effect (the image/video is black/hang).

Can I recover the SS00 SS and save 10 hours game play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My instinct is​ no. I did a little checking, and since the PCSX2 save state file is just a renamed zip file, it's easy enough to look at. The file you're missing in the slot 8 file is just four bytes, 00 00 0B 9A to be specific. You could create that file and name it appropriately to see if that helps.

As for the fully corrupted one, if your hack to load the others doesn't work, it probably won't be recoverable. Sorry. I can't really say more without actually having access to the file.